# Which is the better approach to manipulating record-based data, Arrays or Ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently building a macro to allow me to import an Excel spreadsheet and format the data into a report-like structure.

Thus far I've been able to accomplish this manually using formulas to aggregate the data, but I would like to automate many of these steps.

So, I feel like I have a decision to make.

Since I am importing another Excel file into my Macro-enabled Workbook, do I work with the data by referencing ranges, or do I dump the contents of the file into a Variant Array/Collection/Dict?

I imagine that other people would want to use this "report builder" eventually, so I'm trying to make the conversion as seamless as possible.

Comment: Please saw your macro ??

Comment: The "best" approach is the one you're most comfortable with and which fits your *exact* use case (on which there's not enough information to make a guess as to how you should proceed)

Comment: Doing it in memory should be faster than manipulating range on the worksheet. But as @TimWilliams indicates, the "best" approach is the one you're comfortable with.

Comment: What kind of report are we talking about ? What kind of data do you have ? Do you need to make calculations or any processing on that data or is it only simple sums ? I could help you (this is actually my full-time job) but I need more information.

Comment: I use a database at work, and my only options for output are to a text or excel file.  What is exported is just the raw data.  Using a combination of built-in and custom formulas, as well as named ranges I've been able to automate pretty much all of the calculations/string manipulations I need.  I wouldn't say they are "simple" sums, as most of the formulas rely on SUMIF or SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: @TimWilliams I realize that, but my goal was to garner feedback regarding usability.  I'm not a stranger to programming in general, just VBA.  Personally, I don't like the fixed array size in VBA and I find it a bit more difficult to manipulate record-based array structures.  That doesn't mean I don't want to learn, though.  I usually favour the array because, as David stated, it's memory-efficient, and it masks a lot of the work from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're handling large amounts of data and speed is of vital importance, I would strongly recommend to use Ranges as the main object. The main advantages are:

- Very flexible in addressing ranges, e.g. `Range("A1:B10")`, `Range(TopCell, BottomCell)`, `Range("NamedRange")`
- `.Resize(Rows, Cols)` and ´.Offset(Rows, Cols)` for flexible referencing
- You can basically modify all properties of the range/cells, i.e. not only the `.Value`, but also `.Formula`, `.Font`, `.Border`, ...
- Plenty of methods allow advanced handling (e.g. `.SpecialCells` to find formulas/values/..., `.Rows.Visible` to hide, etc.)
- Loop over all cells in a range with a simple `For Each c in Range("YourRange").Cells` loop

If want to modify anything apart from the value itself, you need to use Ranges. Only if you want to do some complex calculation on a larger dataset, you can improve performance by reading the content of your ranges (or whatever datasource) into an array, process it in the array/in memory and then write the result back into a range in one rush. This approach will significantly increase the calculation speed - but is only applicable in a few situations and recommendable if performance really matters.

Regarding Collections/Dictionaries:
Don't compare them to ranges - they are useful vehicles for certain tasks, esp. when you want to loop over a set of members. But Ranges themselves are a kind of Collection, i.e. you can loop over its elements (just not delete/add new members).
If you want to compare the use of Collections and Dictionary class, here's my quick summary:

Collections are build into VBA, so no need for referencing. The are my main choice for simple aggregations that I want to either loop or address. The advantage of Dictionaries is that they offer additional functionality, mainly a `.Exists` property - and a `.Keys` collection, allowing you to also loop over the keys of the hash. Thus, I reference Dictionary (in the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*) whenever I need those features, but stick to Collections else.

Comment: Thank you Peter!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  One question, though.  How would you go about handling each row within a range as a separate record like in a database?  That has tripped me up a bit lately since obviously, cells and rows aren't the same types of objects.  If anything a row is a group of cell objects, I imagine.

Comment: I'm using Excel tables (Insert->Tables) most of the times. In VBA they are accessible as an ListObject. This object has multiple ranges - the `.DataBodyRange`is the normal range of the data. But you can also access `ListObject.Columns("Your column name").DataBodyRange(RowNumber)`as a Range, so it's pretty versatile...

Comment: Not too well versed in Tables myself.  I'll give it a try though.  Will going this route end up breaking all of my calculated fields, though?

Comment: Any calculation will remain - unless you explicitly overwrite a range with `rng.Value = ...` - this will replace the formula with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of report building tools out there. Making your own seems like wasted effort unless I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.  I think I already have a question floating around here regarding what open source report generators there are out there.  I never received a response.

Comment: [List of open source BI tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence_tools#Open_source_commercial_products).

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Server is free with SQL Server (which you can get for free).

QlikView, which is getting popular now, is free if you sign up.